# Is ReactJs on bower?

Tags: bower, reactjs

I'm very interested in some of the concepts in ReactJs and would like to play around with it. I'm trying to start a project to play around with it but I've been looking all over and I can't seem to find it on bower. But then again bower search kind of sucks...

Is it on there and I'm just not seeing it? If is there something about it that makes it not a good fit for the bower model? I would expect that both projects are popular enough they would work together.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I'm not sure on the particulars of bower, but we have this repository:

https://github.com/reactjs/react-bower

which should be available as `bower install react`.

```
$ bower lookup react
react git://github.com/facebook/react-bower.git
$
```

Comment: Got it. This was the reason for me not finding it: http://bower.io/search/?q=react nothing shows up in the web interface

Comment: Bower supports creating packages. Check out the section 'Defining a package' on [Bower's documentation](http://bower.io)

Comment: It's showing now.  http://bower.io/search/?q=react
Also, getting started docs mention Bower now. https://facebook.github.io/react/downloads.html#bower

Answer (score -6):

To bower installation, you need to install to Git Shell, using command promt of it, your project have got a bower file. When you installed them, you should be follow the command below:

```
> cd d:/yourappfolder/
> bower install
```

Comment: That is not the answer to the question.